# Ограничить область поиска городом пользователя Yandex Mapkit iOS

Tags: ios, swift, yandex-maps-api, yandexmapkit

В примере  Mapkit iOS от Yandex есть класс SuggestTableViewController, в котором приведен пример поиска по карте. В нем находится свойство ограничения области поиска BOUNDING_BOX, которое задается статически. Как мне подстроить это свойство под город пользователя (например, я нахожусь в Казани, и мне нужно, чтобы поиск осуществлялся в пределах этого города)?
Или, может быть, есть конструктор suggestSession.suggest без BOUNDING_BOX?
Нигде не могу найти ответ, буду очень благодарен, если кто-то поможет

Comment: API Яндекса не даёт возможность ограничить поиск городом, областью или иным криволинейным регионом - только BBOX. Если у вас определён город, возможно стоит добавлять к поисковому запросу его название, либо геокодировать город и получив его boundedBy искать в этой зоне.

Comment: Тоже подумал вытащить через геокодирование границы. Но с этим тоже проблема: не могу понять, как получить позицию пользователя в виде YMKPoint, чтобы были известны координаты

Comment: Вообще за положением пользователя должен следить LocationManager https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/android-ref/full/com/yandex/mapkit/location/LocationManager.html?lang=ru Что-то не работает?